# Matlab: Selected data (through brushing) in GUI plot is not being stored

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, store, brush

I am plotting these two curves on an axes:

```
LH(1) = copyobj(T2pb1hLine(2), S.T2pb1Ax(2)); 
LH(2) = copyobj(T2pb1hLine(2), S.T2pb1Ax(2)); 
set(LH(1), 'XData', PressNoOutliers, 'YData', zNoOutliers, 'linestyle',...
            'x', 'Color', 'm');
set(LH(2), 'XData', PressNoOutliers2, 'YData', zNoOutliers2, 'linestyle',...
            's', 'Color', 'b');
```

Then I am using this callback function to brush the data and store it:

```
brush on
pause
hBrushLine = findall(S.T2pb1Ax(2), 'tag', 'Brushing');
brushedData = get(hBrushLine, {'Xdata', 'Ydata'});
brushedIdx = ~isnan(brushedData{1});
PSel = brushedData{1}(brushedIdx);
zSel = brushedData{2}(brushedIdx);
```

I am able to brush the data, however, the data is not being stored which results in empty vectors for `PSel` and `zSel`. Apparently, if I were not using `copyobj` and plotting only single curve then I am able to get the data by brushing for `PSel` and `zSel`. Any guesses what can I do to store the data while I am using `copyobj` to plot the 2 curves together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens:
Depending on the number of lines in your plot, `brushedData` will exceed the currently hard-wired size of `1` in your code. So unless you brush data from the first line, `Psel` and `zSel` will be empty, because `brushedData{1}` will only contain `NaN` - and the data you meant to select was in `brushedData{n}` (corresponding to the `n`-th line), but never got processed. Here's a little example (you will have to adjust the `gca` and such handles, but the logic becomes clear):

```
x1 = linspace(1,10,21);
y1 = rand(1,21);

x2 = x1;
y2 = rand(1,21);

x3 = x2;
y3 = rand(1,21);

h(1) = plot(x1,y1,'b');

h(2) = copyobj(h(1),gca); 
h(3) = copyobj(h(1),gca); 

set(h(2),'XData',x2,'YData',y2,'Color','r')
set(h(3),'XData',x3,'YData',y3,'Color','g')

brush on
pause
hBrushLine = findall(gca, 'tag', 'Brushing');
brushedData = get(hBrushLine, {'Xdata', 'Ydata'});

for I=1:size(brushedData,1)
    brushedIdx = ~isnan(brushedData{I,1});
    PSel{I} = brushedData{I,1}(brushedIdx);
    zSel{I} = brushedData{I,2}(brushedIdx);
end
```

Depending on which line you choose your data from, some cells in `Psel` and `zSel` turn up empty. I chose to go with cells, because it allows you to select a different amount of points from different lines.

Comment: @Pupil Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hey, thanks. Apparently, I just received the notification of your answer now even though it was answered like 42 min ago. 

Yeah it works perfectly fine. But, I have one question though. Even though I have two plots on my axes, the size of `brushedData` is `3 x 1` - any idea why? I am sending the two plots to the axes defined outside the function as `S.T2pb1Ax(3) = axes('Parent', T2hbox1, 'OuterPosition', [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]);  
T2pb1hLine(3) = plot(NaN, NaN, 'Parent', S.T2pb1Ax(3));`

Comment: @Pupil : Maybe, because your initial plot of `Nan,NaN` generates the `+1` line object? Even though there is nothing, the brush still considers it. You can probably do away with the first copy of the line object and modify your `NaN,NaN`-line, by setting (for example): `LH(1) = T2pb1hLine(2)`.

Comment: I am sorry, it should be: `S.T2pb1Ax(2) = axes('Parent', T2hbox1, 'OuterPosition', [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]);  
T2pb1hLine(2) = plot(NaN, NaN, 'Parent', S.T2pb1Ax(2));`. Now if I remove `T2pb1hLine(2) = plot(NaN, NaN, 'Parent', S.T2pb1Ax(2))` then what would happen to `LH(1)` and `LH(2)` as they use `T2pb1hLine(2)`

Comment: Don't remove the `plot(NaN,NaN ...` part - you need that to initialize the plot (and the line object). Much rather, instead of making two copies for `LH(1)` and `LH(2)`, set `LH(1)` to `T2pb1hLine(2)` (the line object handle of `plot(NaN,NaN ...` - that way, you update that line object for your first line and the copy (`LH(2)`) for your second line.